# Getting Integer Value from a Modbus RTU Slave using Python Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, modbus, pymodbus

I am reading the values in the registers of a modbus slave. But the values stored in the registers is combination of two registers. That is if register 3 has 72, and register 4 has 489. The actual value is 72489. I was able to do this.

But the problem arises, when the value in the second register starts with 0. That is if register 2 has 72, and register 4 has 012. The actual value should be 72012, but I get 7212. Is there a way to prevent this.

The part of code which does this is,

```
`rr = client.read_holding_registers(2, 22, unit=1)
 unconcatenateSensorConsumptionValues = rr.registers
 sensorsConsumptionValues = []
 for i in range(0, 10, 2):
    ftemp = ""+str(unconcatenateSensorConsumptionValues[i])
    stemp = ""+str(unconcatenateSensorConsumptionValues[i+1])
    fin = ftemp+stemp
    sensorsConsumptionValues.append(int(fin))`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it or not,I got two solution:

First Solution: fill one register up to 65535 and add remaining to the other register. So the actual value will be addition of first and second register. But here we can have a max value of 131070(65535+65535).

Second Solution: convert the value into hex and then divide the two octets and convert to decimal. Now store those decimal in the modbus registers. To get the original Value. Read the two modbus registers, convert them into hex, convert the both hex values combined to a decimal value. This decimal value is the actual value. In this way the maximum value can be stored with two registers is 4294967295.

To understand easily, I attached a Image(I created using MS Paint but is there any easy way)

This can be used for multiples registers and can use for big numbers.

.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Treat the registers numerically not as strings.

`fin = int(unconcatenateSensorConsumptionValues[i]) * 1000 + int(unconcatenateSensorConsumptionValues[i+1]) * 1`

The first register is the 1000's the second register is the 1's.

Comment: its not constant, the values will change like, register 3 having 732, and register 4 having 0068.What to do in those cases. As the actual value should be, 7320068.

Comment: I suspect you are misunderstanding what is in the registers. A modbus register is 16 bits. Now that could store 2 characters (8-bit each) or actually store a number. That number would be an integer between −32,768 to 32,767 or if negative numbers aren't allowed: 0 to 65535.
Leading zeroes would not be produced by the library - it is a number, it should never be converted to a string.

Comment: The slave needs to store the values in the registers is more than the single register limit(65535). So its using two registers to store the value, by splitting into two parts. I think the best way is to change the way slave stores the values. Can you suggest any better way to store values higher than 65535 in the slave.